# Which package would produce a chemical equation hierarchy like this?

Tags: chemistry, mhchem

Trying to replicate this style of yield arrows I saw in a paper for when more than one product can be produced. Specifically the multiple dropped yield arrows. How would I do that in Tex? I have the MHCHEM package, no seeing a way to achieve this. Thanks!

```
\documentclass[12pt]
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \ce{e^-{} + CH4 -> H^- + H^- + CH2}
  \label{eq:3frag}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Such as \begin{equation}
  \ce{e^-{} + CF4 -> F^- + F + CF2}
\end{equation}

Comment: I can add packages if you'd like, but the original question is WHICH package...

Comment: There is a picture bud. Problem has been solved, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proposal. (I know of course that the equation does not make any sense from a chemistry point of view, I just copied something.) You can use `tikz` with `tikzmark` along with `align` from `amsmath`, which gets loaded by `mhchem`.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align} 
\tikzmarknode{L}{\ce{e^-{} + CH4 -> H^- + H^- + CH2}}\qquad &\notag\\
& \tikzmarknode{R1}{\ce{e^-{} + CH4 -> H^- + H^- + CH2}}\label{eq:3fraga} \\
& \tikzmarknode{R2}{\ce{e^-{} + CH4 -> H^- + H^- + CH2}} \\
& \tikzmarknode{R3}{\ce{e^-{} + CH4 -> H^- + H^- + CH2}} \\
& \tikzmarknode{R4}{\ce{e^-{} + CH4 -> H^- + H^- + CH2}} \\
& \tikzmarknode{R5}{\ce{e^-{} + CH4 -> H^- + H^- + CH2}} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \foreach \X in {1,...,5}
 {\draw[semithick,-stealth,shorten <=1.5pt,shorten >=1.5pt] (L.east) -- ++ (1em,0) |- (R\X.west);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

[image]